# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with Hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, properties, configuration

I have 2 files which need to be bound together: hibernate.cfg.xml and hibernate properties.
How can I point them to each other using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer? Is it possible without declaring them as a beans?(I'm beginner in Spring). Every answer is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Nazar

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
           <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="db">
            <value>hibernate.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">${db.dialect}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${db.driver}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">${db.url}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">${db.username}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">${db.password}</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">${db.pool_size}</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">${db.current_session_context_class}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">${db.show_sql}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${db.provider_class}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${db.use_second_level_cache}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${db.use_query_cache}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${db.hbm2ddl_auto}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">${db.import_files}</property>
        <mapping class="com.dataart.mediaportal.model.User"/>
        <mapping class="com.dataart.mediaportal.model.Album"/>
        <mapping class="com.dataart.mediaportal.model.Role"/>
        <mapping class="com.dataart.mediaportal.model.Image"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hibernate.properties:

```
db.username=postgres
db.password=4351
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/MediaPortalDB
db.pool_size=1
db.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
db.import_files=import.sql
db.hbm2ddl_auto=create
db.use_query_cache=true
db.use_second_level_cache=true
db.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
db.show_sql=true
db.current_session_context_class=thread
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can access both the files and use them to create the Session Factory. But instead of doing this inside your hibernate configuration file. I would suggest to do it inside the application context because first, your hibernate.cfg.xml does not contain the name space required to declare the bean and secondly. it needs to be read by the context configurer so, that it can instantiate the bean.

In you application context, you can create a data source using the hibernate.properties file like this..

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
p:location="{location of hibernate properties files}" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.databaseurl}"/>
    ....other properties...
</bean>
```

Finally, create a session factory like this

```
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="configLocation">
            <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="configurationClass">
            <beans:value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
```

This would create a session factory singleton instance for you which could be accessed using Autowiring.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try in a moment and let you know if that solution works.

Comment: Be sure to use the appropriate package, like hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean that matches your version of hibernate. Also include the spring-orm dependency.