# How to include properties from external file to hibernate.cfg.xml?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I need to be able to store database config properties in `src|main|java|dbConnection.properties` and  include it to `hibernate.cfg.xml` in form of **jstl** expressions. (like : ${password} etc.). How to do it?

**Current hibernate.cfg.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">postgres</property>
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**I need something like this:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
            "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
            "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">${DRIVER}</property>
            <property name="connection.username">${USERNAME}</property>
            <property name="connection.password">${PASSWORD}</property>
            <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: If you are using Spring why even bother with a hibernate.cfg.xml. Configure the `SessionFactory` in spring and let spring handle the placeholder replacement for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You state that you use Spring then why not let Spring do all the hard work. Let a property placeholder replace the placeholders you want.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:dbConnection.properties" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <map>
            <entry key="connection.driver_class" value="${DRIVER}" />
            <entry key="connection.username" value="${USERNAME}" />
            <entry key="connection.password" value="${PASSWORD}" />
            <entry key="transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory" />
        </map>
    <property>
 </bean>
```

Free advice instead of using the internal hibernate connection stuff (which isn't adviced to be used in production) configure a datasource in spring and wire that to your `LocalSessionFactoryBean`

Comment: I'm new to Hibernate. Can you give all example configuration needed for this set up? What config should be left in `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

Comment: Everything you need is in the answer. So no hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: Be sure to use the appropriate package, like hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean that matches your version of hibernate. Also include the spring-orm dependency.

Comment: where to find complete list of entry keys?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it programmatically.

hibernate.cfg.xml should be as following.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
            "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
            "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

dbConnection.properties

```
connection.driver_class=org.postgresql.Driver
connection.username=postgres
connection.password=postgres
```

And when creating the `SessionFactory` you can do the following.

```
Properties dbConnectionProperties = new Properties();
try {
    dbConnectionProperties.load(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dbConnection.properties"));
} catch(Exception e) {
    // Log
}

SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().mergeProperties(dbConnectionProperties).configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: The `load` method of `dbConnectionProperties` cannot be of type `String`. IDE suggests: void load(Reader) OR  void load(InputStream). How to fix it?

Comment: Thanks! Recently found another way of doing it. Why your solution is better than this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939339/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-with-hibernate-cfg-xml ?

Comment: For future reference of anyone trying to implement this solution, you need to use `hibernate.connection.username` in the properties file (as well as for password and any other parameter that needs to be injected into the `<hibernate-configuration>` tag).

Answer (score 5):

Following [this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-filter-resources-based-on-values-from-a-properties-file.html), [this](http://www.manydesigns.com/en/portofino/portofino3/tutorials/using-maven-profiles-and-resource-filtering/#TOC-Resource-filtering) and [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) I came up with the following Maven configuration that replaces/filters placeholders from your hibernate.cfg.xml file with properties from a properties file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>

                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <!-- here the phase you need -->
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/extra-resources</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <!-- Specify the file that contains the value to replace the placeholders -->
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/dbConnection.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <includes>
                <include>hibernate.cfg.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

With this configuration, you can run the *validate* Maven goal to generate the filtered files and see if they are relpaced correctly

This is of course useful if you are using Maven.