# db properties for hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I try to connect to a postgresql database using hibernate in Java 1.8.

My hibernate.cfg.xml has variables that I defined in a db.properties file.

I try several ways, but it doesn't work for me.

My code:

```
    File f = new File("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    java.util.Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("db.properties"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(properties.getProperty("db.addr"));
    System.out.println(properties.getProperty("db.port"));

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(); configuration.configure(f).addProperties(properties);

    ServiceRegistryBuilder registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
    registry.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = registry.buildServiceRegistry();

    // loads configuration and mappings
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);


       // obtains the session
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    .....


    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml is below:

```
    <!-- JDBC Properties -->

    <property name="connection.driver_class">
        org.postgresql.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">
        org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
    </property>
    <property name="connection.url">
        jdbc:postgresql://${db.addr}:${db.port}/metadata
    </property>
     ..........
```

........

The configuration still uses ${db.addr}:${db.port}

[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://${db.addr}:${db.port}/metadata

Did I miss something?

Thanks much

Comment: Is there any exception ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set       --- This does not happen if I have the values in the hibernate.cfg.xml instead of the placeholders

Comment: where are you keeping the values of placeholders?

Comment: I have the placeholders in db.properties that I load in the beginning: db.addr=localhost
db.port=5432

Comment: which version of spring are you using? Can you paste the application context.xml file?

Comment: I have spring 3.2.8.  I don't have a context.xml

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176024/how-to-include-properties-from-external-file-to-hibernate-cfg-xml

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that one.  The problem is I want to be able to bind to different properties files at runtime.

Comment: What do you mean by "at runtime"? Do you mean on startup?

Comment: I want to to be able to swap out properties files to connect to different database per user's action.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments... I decided to use system env variables and change them when needed.