# How to support different Databases without the need to rebuild

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, persistence.xml

[Why do I need to configure the SQL dialect of a data source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012799/why-do-i-need-to-configure-the-sql-dialect-of-a-data-source) argues that one must define the `hibernate.dialect`.

But, if `hiberate.dialect` is defined within `persistence.xml`, I have to decide **at build time**, which database is to be used. What can be done to defer the decision until **deployment time**.

The goal is to provide a war file without knowing the database in advance.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176024/how-to-include-properties-from-external-file-to-hibernate-cfg-xml)

Comment: Doesn't hibernate detect the necessary dialect on its own if you leave out the property?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, Hibernate will not deploy properly if you do not set a dialect