# How to read database configuration parameter using properties file in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

In my apps I am using hibernate, to connect a with database and create a session. this is my hibernate.cfg.xml file. This is ok. It working properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/country</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

But when I try to read the DB configuration properties using `db.property file` using this `hibernate.cfg.xml`, it showing Exception, this is my another `hibernate.cfg.xml` file

```
<util:properties id="db" location="classpath:db.properties" />

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="driverClassName" value="#{db['driverClassName']}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="#{db['url']}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="#{db['username']}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="#{db['password']}"></property>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

this is the error

```
 org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 8 of document  : The prefix "util" for       element "util:properties" is not bound. Nested exception: The prefix "util" for element   "util:properties" is not bound.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2155)
```

this is my properties file named `db.properties`

```
driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/country

username=root

password=password
```

what is the problem is there?
how to do that properly

Comment: if you are using spring then you can refer this link,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939339/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-with-hibernate-cfg-xml

Comment: I read that, but I need to do it in hibernate only, not using spring.  Because I want my hibernate application to get the DB configuration properties from properties file.

Comment: @Killer does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176024/how-to-include-properties-from-external-file-to-hibernate-cfg-xml) helps you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`util:properties` is not a valid tag to use in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. If you want to place all the DB configuration details in a properties file then you can place them in `hibernate.properties` file and remove those from `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. In this way the DB details will be maintained in properties file.

If you want to maintain a separate file instead of using hibernate.properties file then you can try this:

```
java.util.Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("db.properties"));

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addProperties(properties);;

ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
.applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration
.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Answer (score 5):

try this code:

hibernate.properties

```
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/country
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=123
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
import java.util.Properties;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {

        Properties dbConnectionProperties = new Properties();
        try {
            dbConnectionProperties.load(HibernateUtil.class.getClassLoader().getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hibernate.properties"));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Log
        }           

        return new AnnotationConfiguration().mergeProperties(dbConnectionProperties).configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();          


    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
//            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
    return null;
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
     <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> 

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <!--<mapping class="net.viralpatel.hibernate.Employee"/>-->
    <!--<mapping class="net.viralpatel.hibernate.PersonEntity"/>-->
    <mapping class="mobin.FavaEmail.entities.PersonEntity"/>
    <mapping class="mobin.FavaEmail.entities.OrgEntity"/>
    <mapping class="mobin.FavaEmail.entities.User"/>


</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Where would "HibernateUtil.java" go in my project? I'm not clear as to how  my project would know to use this file...

Comment: use where that  you want to create seassionFactory.         
SessionFactory  factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

Answer (score 1):

**1) Hibernate configuration XML file: Hibernateconfig.cfg.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"></property>
        <property name="show_sql"></property>
        <property name="format_sql"></property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto"></property>

        <mapping class="SourceFields"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**2) Hibernate properties file - config.properties**

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9191/Register
hibernate.connection.username=username
hibernate.connection.password=password
hibernate.connection.pool_size=10
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
show_sql=true
format_sql=true
hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

**3) Loading properties file:**

```
public static Properties propertyLoad() {
        Properties properties = null;
        if (properties == null) {
            properties = new Properties();
            try {
                properties.load(PropertiesUtil.class
                        .getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return properties;
    }
```

**4) Creation of session factory:**

```
public class HibernateBaseDB {

    private static Properties properties = new Properties();

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        properties = PropertiesUtil.propertyLoad();
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.configure("Hibrnateconfig.cfg.xml")
                      .addProperties(properties);

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                .buildServiceRegistry();

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration
                .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        return sessionFactory;

    }
```

*Here you can configure the DB credentials from properties file to xml file at run time and you can create session factory using the xml file.
The xml file will be configured according to the credentials given in the properties file.*

You can call the static method of **HibernateBaseDB** class, getSessionFactory(), wherever you need to create a session factory.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateBaseDB.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```