# How to read database configuration parameter from config file in hibernate

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I create a simple hibernate sample . it work correctly. now i want to read database configuration parameter that is in hibernate.cfg.xml file from a properties file. I found an example in "[How to read database configuration parameter using properties file in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684785/how-to-read-database-configuration-parameter-using-properties-file-in-hibernate) " and do that. but i have this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3996)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1284)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2142)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:781)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:27)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:127)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1300)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
at organizationsTab.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:14)
at organizationsTab.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
at shiroLogin.CustomSecurityRealm.getPasswordForUser(CustomSecurityRealm.java:111)
at shiroLogin.CustomSecurityRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(CustomSecurityRealm.java:83)
at shiroLogin.LoadDriver.submit(LoadDriver.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1763)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1651)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonSkin$1.run(ButtonSkin.java:103)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.KeyboardShortcutsHandler.processAccelerators(KeyboardShortcutsHandler.java:350)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.KeyboardShortcutsHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(KeyboardShortcutsHandler.java:168)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.forwardToParent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:505)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.fire(TextFieldBehavior.java:190)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(TextInputControlBehavior.java:187)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:222)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:137)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase$1.handle(BehaviorBase.java:136)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase$1.handle(BehaviorBase.java:133)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3949)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$2100(Scene.java:3896)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2036)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2493)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:123)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:197)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:517)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:927)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.access$200(GtkApplication.java:48)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$6$1.run(GtkApplication.java:149)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jan 27, 2015 9:08:28 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
SEVERE: could not complete schema update
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3996)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1284)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2142)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:781)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:27)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:127)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1300)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
at organizationsTab.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:14)
at organizationsTab.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
at shiroLogin.CustomSecurityRealm.getPasswordForUser(CustomSecurityRealm.java:111)
at shiroLogin.CustomSecurityRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(CustomSecurityRealm.java:83)
at shiroLogin.LoadDriver.submit(LoadDriver.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1763)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1651)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonSkin$1.run(ButtonSkin.java:103)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.KeyboardShortcutsHandler.processAccelerators(KeyboardShortcutsHandler.java:350)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.KeyboardShortcutsHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(KeyboardShortcutsHandler.java:168)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.forwardToParent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:505)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.fire(TextFieldBehavior.java:190)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(TextInputControlBehavior.java:187)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:222)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:137)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase$1.handle(BehaviorBase.java:136)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase$1.handle(BehaviorBase.java:133)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3949)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$2100(Scene.java:3896)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2036)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2493)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:123)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:197)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:517)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:927)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.access$200(GtkApplication.java:48)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$6$1.run(GtkApplication.java:149)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

 Jan 27, 2015 9:08:28 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 1045, SQLState: 28000
Jan 27, 2015 9:08:28 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1768)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1651)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonSkin$1.run(ButtonSkin.java:103)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.KeyboardShortcutsHandler.processAccelerators(KeyboardShortcutsHandler.java:350)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.KeyboardShortcutsHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(KeyboardShortcutsHandler.java:168)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.forwardToParent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:505)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.fire(TextFieldBehavior.java:190)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(TextInputControlBehavior.java:187)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:222)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:137)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase$1.handle(BehaviorBase.java:136)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase$1.handle(BehaviorBase.java:133)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3949)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$2100(Scene.java:3896)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2036)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2493)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:123)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:197)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:517)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:927)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.access$200(GtkApplication.java:48)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$6$1.run(GtkApplication.java:149)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1763)
... 63 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:426)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:119)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
at shiroLogin.CustomSecurityRealm.getPasswordForUser(CustomSecurityRealm.java:113)
at shiroLogin.CustomSecurityRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(CustomSecurityRealm.java:83)
at shiroLogin.LoadDriver.submit(LoadDriver.java:90)
... 73 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3996)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1284)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2142)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:781)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
... 80 more
```

in hibernate.cfg.xml file i want to get database name , username and password from a properties file that is next to hibernate.cfg.xml file.

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ ${hibernate['dbName']} ?characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>
    <property name="connection.username">${hibernate['user']}</property>
    <property name="connection.password">${hibernate['pass']}</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <!--<mapping class="net.viralpatel.hibernate.Employee"/>-->
    <!--<mapping class="net.viralpatel.hibernate.PersonEntity"/>-->
    <mapping class="organizationsTab.PersonEntity"/>
    <mapping class="organizationsTab.OrgEntity"/>
    <mapping class="organizationsTab.User"/>


</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hibernate.properties:

```
dbName=emailDB
user=root
pass=123
```

Comment: Can you connect to database from localhost using the same credentials. Try this : mysql -uroot -p123

Comment: yes i can. my sample work correctly but when i want to read parameters from properties file it not work.

Comment: why are you using ${hibernate['dbName']}? just use "${dbName}" and remove extra spaces from your URL as well

Comment: I test it but i have same exception

Comment: where have you specified which file to use?

Answer (score 0):

Use following configuration:-

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${dbName}?characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>
<property name="connection.username">${user}</property>
<property name="connection.password">${pass}</property>
```

Comment: I test it but i have same exception

Comment: Is Your hibernate.properties in a root directory of the classpath.  Please go through the following [link] (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

ok you need to do this

```
  <bean id="configure"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
  p:location="{property file location}" />
```

at the start (inside session-factory)
then you can specify configuration as

```
<property name="connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${dbName}?characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
<property name="connection.username" value="${user}">
<property name="connection.password" value="${pass}"/>
```

hope this helps!

Good luck!