# Liquibase and Hibernate read from same properties file

Tags: java, hibernate, properties, liquibase

I am using both `Liquibase` and `Hibernate` libraries in my application. They both work with the same database, but each requires it's own `properties` file. However, some of the database-specific fields are common. I would like to avoid duplication of those fields and having them in both files. I would like to have those properties in a single file that Liquibase and Hibernate properties file would read from.

Currently I have.

**liquibase.properties**

```
driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
username: root
password: root
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
```

Note how driver, URL, username and password are duplicated in those 2 files. Ideally, I'd have some 3rd file like this.

**database.properties**

```
driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
username: root
password: root
```

And then something like.

**liquibase.properties**

```
driver: ${driver}
url: ${url}
username: ${username}
password: ${password}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">${driver}</property>
        <property name="connection.url">${url}</property>
        <property name="connection.username">${username}</property>
        <property name="connection.password">${password}</property>
```

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SO answer (and question) that shows how to put hibernate db config in a property file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25685198/332248

Here is documentation on liquibase how to set a properties file for liquibase (using the `--defaultsFile` option): http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html

So it should be possible to combine everything into one hibernate.properties file and then specify the same file when running liquibase.