# hibernate.cfg.xml - Set parameters from a properties file

Tags: java, hibernate

I've this file **hibernate.cfg.xml** that I use to configure hibernate at sturtup.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">dbUser</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">1234</property>
```

I've a properties file that it's called **config.properties** that hold all other configurations used into the application.

How can I set **"hibernate.connection.username"** parameter from the properties file (config.properties) so I have only one file to edit?

Comment: [Are you searching for something like this ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939339/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-with-hibernate-cfg-xml)

Comment: @NeerajJain that works when using an IoC and dependency injection framework like Spring (as shown in that link). In case you don't use it, you can do it with a little more effort.

Comment: there is no way to set parameters from Java code during hibernate startup?

Comment: AFAIK the best way is to create a `DataSource` using Apache DBCP, C3P0, HikariCP or another vendor, and then follow the steps shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4406935/1065197. Note that when you create your `DataSource` instance, you can apply the parameters from a properties file as you want/need.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I've found that which work for me:  configuration.setProperty( "hibernate.connection.username", "1234" ); What do you think about?

Comment: Post it as an answer then, but I don't recommend you using that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me is that, Adding a properties at runtime into the configuration:

```
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", Config.db.getUser());
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the destination of the properties stored in config.properties

If they go in the java System properties, you can use them in your hibernate config like this :

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">${propertyName}</property>
```

If your properties go somewhere else, then I don't think hibernate will see them naturally...

Comment: Yes is used somewhere else. How can I allow Hibernate to see this properties?

Answer (score 0):

I do it like that:

```
Map<String, Object> prop = new HashMap<String, Object>();

prop.put("hibernate.connection.username", "asdf");
prop.put("hibernate.connection.password", "xxx");


Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName, prop);
```